# How to upload file on ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am playing with jQuery Ajax and I want to upload file to specific folder on ajax response.

My HTML Form:

```
<form type="post" method="post" action="" id="newCustomerForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input name="username" id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <input name="message" id="message" type="text" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <label for="file">File</label>
        <input name="file" id="file" type="file" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addCustomer"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My Ajax Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#newCustomerForm").validate({
        rules: {
            "username": {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "username": {
                required: "Please, enter a name"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data: $(form).serialize()+'&file='+document.getElementById('file').value,
                timeout: 3000,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#feedback").html(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I am getting ajax data inside bellow function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_addCustomer', 'addCustomer');
function addCustomer() {
    echo $username = $_POST['username'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $message = $_POST['message'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $file = $_POST['file'];
    echo "<br />";  
    die(); 
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addCustomer', 'addCustomer');
```

I am getting file name on response but I am confused how to upload image to specific folder on my project folder.

I will appreciate If you help me to solve my issue.

Thanks :)

Comment: You can't upload files with regular Ajax you need to work with [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to upload files asynchronously.

Comment: File uploads are handled server side